# What are ASP 0115 and C0000005 errors?

Tags: asp

My Window Server 2003 running ASP keeps getting 500 errors on occasions. The htm is mapped to the ASP engine in IIS. My backend is connecting to MySQL using MySQL ODBC 5.01 connector. The error page is like below:

Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0115'

Unexpected error

/Index.htm

A trappable error (C0000005) occurred in an external object. The script cannot continue running.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading to a newer ODBC connector, version 5.1.6 should have this bug fixed.

See also:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36823

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44971