# Error: File home.asp Unexpected error. A trappable error (C0000005) occurred in an external object. Using ODBC Connector

Tags: iis, database, odbc, asp-classic, dsn

How can I get my application pool to stop crashing on me?

### Background

All was working well for many years, until I updated Windows 10 Pro to the suggested update *Windows Feature Experience Pack*.

[image]

Current System:

> Edition    Windows 10 Pro
> Version    21H2
> Installed on   ‎8/‎24/‎2020
> OS build   19044.1415
> Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0

This must have probably changed some user permissions and the way IIS was working; and to the point where I lost my website. I had to reinstall everything.

### Error (C0000005)

It has been four weeks now since I've updated from MariaDB 10.1 to MariaDB 10.6 and with that, I changed from using MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver to MariaDB Connector/ODBC 3.1 (Version 3.01.15.00) which is part of the "*current stable release series*."

These not very helpful errors are missing line number information where the error is. They read:

> File /home.asp Unexpected error. A trappable error (C0000005) occurred in an external object. The script cannot continue running.

And look like this:

[image: error (C0000005)]

---

**What I did:**

I checked my code for left open connections to the database as suggested in this post [Classic ASP C0000005 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649487/classic-asp-c0000005-error-on-execution) but I am still getting these errors. These random (C0000005) ASP errors keep bringing the application pool down and are very much behaving as described in [this thread](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36823) where some memory leak may be to blame for.

Now I am considering using a different driver.

The answers in this thread [What are ASP 0115 and C0000005 Errors](https://serverfault.com/questions/109050/what-are-asp-0115-and-c0000005-errors) suggests using ODBC connector version 5.1.6 (mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.6-winx64.msi) which is from 2009. This [MySQL Connector/ODBC 8.0.27](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) (mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.27-winx64.msi) looks more up to date. And I should give it a try.

First thing I've noticed it is much much faster. Now I am just hoping that these C0000005 Errors will end.

---

**Update A:** Errors are still returning, but much sooner as anticipated.

I tried the **32-bit** driver as well mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.27-win32.msi to see if that would work but could not even get the page to load. I guess I would need to use a 32-bit application pool for it to work. (Have not tried that.)

---

**Update B:** I am now back using **64-bit MySQL Connector/ODBC 8.0.27** driver.

Could it be the way I configure the driver that brings my application pool down?

This is my connection string:

```
Conn_STRING = "dsn=___;" & _
   "TCPIP=1;" & _
   "SERVER=127.0.0.1;" & _
   "UID=___;" & _
   "PWD=___;" & _
   "DATABASE=___;" & _
   "PORT=3306;" & _
   "CONN_TIMEOUT=30;" & _
   "CHARSET=utf8mb4;" & _
   "READ_TIMEOUT=20;" & _
   "WRITE_TIMEOUT=10;" & _
   "Option=3"
```

I set the connection parameters as such:

[image: connection]

[image: metadata]

[image: cursor/results]

[image: debug]

[image: ssl]

[image: misc]

I noticed that somehow the application pool somehow keeps running despite these loged Erross:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Active Server Pages" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="49152">5</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-12-23T21:41:37.9772561Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>2212200</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" /> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>vm-white</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>File /blog.asp Unexpected error. A trappable error (C0000005) occurred in an external object. The script cannot continue running.</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

I am also seeing a new Warning in the System Log.

[image: A process serving application pool 'myPool' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '1124'. The data field contains the error number.]

---

### UPDATE

I tired many different ODBC drivers. MariaDB ODBC and MySQL ODBC drivers. None keeps the application pool from crashing. Before crashing lots of C0000005 errors get logged. The MySQL ODBC 8.0 driver turned out to be much faster and more forgiving, but something is still bring the application pool down. I am now using MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode driver.

[MariaDB ODBC has a bug?](http://mariadb.com/kb/en/asp-c0000005-errors-with-mariadb-connectorodbc-3115-64bit/)

Furthermore, I now changed the way I am setting objects. Instead of setting them like this

```
SET rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
SET wshell = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
SET message = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
```

I'm now just doing

```
SET rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
SET wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
SET message = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
```

It is staring to look more promising. Some errors have now sometimes line numbers.

I contacted Microsoft to help me interpret [my DebugDiag Analysis Report](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/679580/a-trappable-error-c0000005-occurred-in-an-external.html) of these crashes. I also noticed a new pattern that started to show in the error logs. First a **Active Server Pages** followed by **Application Error**:

[image: error pattern]

**Active Server Pages Error:**

> Error: File /blog.asp  Unexpected error. A trappable error (C0000005)  occurred in an external object. The script cannot continue running..

**Application Error:**

> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.19041.1,  time stamp: 0x58c67bf3
> Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1288, time stamp: 0xa280d1d6
> Exception code: 0xc0000409
> Fault offset: 0x00000000000a2070
> Faulting process id: 0x3144
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d7fd9d0686ef42
> Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
> Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
> Report Id: cda5aa10-492d-4e5c-ae17-ac4f9dbf70ab
> Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

---

As suggested [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-apptips-microsoft-asp.html) at mysql.com I now changed my DSN connector setting for use with ASP. I checked to box `Return matched rows instead of effected rows`.

I had `Option=3` in my connection string and found based on [this blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407841/whats-the-option-n-in-the-mysql-odbc-connection-string) that I should probably declare it as `FLAG_FIELD_LENGTH` (1) + `FLAG_FOUND_ROWS` (2).

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being the database driver causing the problem. Using the `MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver` works.

[image]

... with using this to connect to it:

```
MM_Connection_STRING = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};" & _
                       "PORT=_;" & _
                       "SERVER=127.0.0.1;" & _
                       "UID=_;" & _
                       "PWD=_;" & _
                       "DATABASE=_;" & _
                       "Option=3;" & _
                       "CHARSET=utf8mb4"
```

Insightful info from ChatGTP

> In general, for Classic ASP applications, using the ODBC connector might be the most straightforward and widely supported choice, given that Classic ASP is designed to work with ADO. However, if you're dealing with a mixed technology stack involving both Classic ASP and .NET, you might need to consider a combination of connectors based on your specific requirements.