# Windows MariaDB 10.6.5 upgrade to MariaDB 10.6.11

Tags: windows, mariadb, upgrade, odbc, mysql8

I am considering upgrading my MariaDB 10.6 to 10.11 -- (maintained for 5 years).

I updated 10.6.5 to 10.6.15 with a simple in-place update; but found these troubling comments on doing updates form 10.6 to 10.11: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading-mariadb-on-windows/#comment_6240

> Upgrading from MariaDB 10.6/10.8/10.9 => 10.11 dosn't work on Windows

I had ODBC driver problems in the passed [Error: File home.asp Unexpected error. A trappable error (C0000005) occurred in an external object. Using ODBC Connector](https://serverfault.com/questions/1088102/error-file-home-asp-unexpected-error-a-trappable-error-c0000005-occurred-in) so I am a bit hesitant to even update.

What would an update bring?

Thank you for sharing your insight.